# Unilateral closure of quotes

Tags: discussion

Can I check [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/49707/8309) unilateral closure?

Doesn't it still relate to history, notwithstanding "a figure of speech, the implication of which is explained right afterwards in the source quote"?

Comment: Title: Isn't thjs about a closure of a *question* instead of a quote?

Answer (score 6):

Just because something was written in the recent past, does not mean it's necessarily about history or in scope here. History.SE is not a service for explaining simple English sentences which can be understood independently of any historical context.

Again, the original source explained what the quote means in the very next sentence.